# How to load attribute of a link in single page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to achieve a single page app and doing fine already but suddenly I have hit this problem.

1. My app was formerly multipage but now single page. I have a link that points to `<a href="loadpost.html?id=12 . loadpost.html>` used to be an external page, but now I have added it as a data role to index. So it should read something like: `index.html#loadpost?id=12`, how do I add the id filter to it.
2. I have a link on a page that links to  `window.location.href = "index.html"`, how do I achieve so it goes to `window.location.href = #index` and I don't want to reload the page.

Comment: "need your help urgently" — No you don't. This is by no means something with huge implications, and implying we should help you over others because of time-sensitivity is disrespectful to everyone else.

Comment: Thanks @jhpratt.. As you can see Im barely new here and I dont meant to be in anyway disrespecting. As simple as that look, it stopping me. I have been on this project for 4 weeks and im glad my first google bound app is almost ready, but I just decided why not single page, then I hit that. I intend working all all, if I dont settle that now, I will spend all nite trying to figure it out since I have been on it few hours before I opted for help here. & you shouldn't be quite hard on someone who is trying to get help, I bet you were once new too..You were quite hard.

Comment: I'm not being hard on you asking for help. I'm being hard on the way you've worded it.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers, and we expect people to know this already as a matter of common manners. Please refrain from adding this to your questions. cc @jhpratt

Comment: Thank you. I lost four points over this question already.

Comment: Well , I am new, and there other nicer way you could show me my mistake. I ain't here to break rules, but to get help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To change hash use:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href + "#index";
```

To get event for change hash use:

```
if ("onhashchange" in window) {

}
```

for get hash value use:

```
window.location.hash
```